# Отправка писем в MVC фреймеворках

Tags: email, php, mvc

Добрый день!
Вопрос следующий: кто где выполняет формирование письма и отправляет письма в MVC фреймворках.
У меня например формирование письма выполняется в контроллере, из БД с помощью модели достается только шаблон письма.
мб есть смысл делать все это в модели и потом просто вызывать sendMail контроллера с параметрами из модели?
Делимся своими соображениями.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Зависит от подхода. К примеру у меня есть модель Users, в которой есть метод addUser, который вызывается при регистрации. В этом же методе формируется объект Zend_Mail и формирует письмо активации, там же оно и отправляется. Т.е. все действия происходят в модели. В контроллер возвращается либо true либо false идальше уже контроллер думает, что вызывать views удачной регистрации, либо же что-то другое.

Comment: ну модели уже есть, письма всегда отправляются после методов saveUser либо saveTransaction в модели. Вариантов писем много.

Comment: я Вас понял, спасибо. Именно это хотел узнать

Comment: Отправка из модели — это уже, если придираться — не совсем MVC: в модели оказывается кусок логики, не совсем ей свойственный. Если хочется чистоты структуры — можно использовать [observer pattern](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)), модель будет слать сигналы наблюдателям, а те — рассылать почту, уведомлять админов, резервировать услуги и что там может понадобиться.

Comment: не, сама отправка идет из контроллера. App::controller()->sendMail($params); этот метод вызываю из модели после сохранения при определенных условиях. Переделал под эту идею, лишился много проблем. всем спасибо